# Is it possible to build a web application as a generic product rather than a one-time customized solution?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, enterprise-architect

There is a business problem that needs to be solved. The obvious solution is an enterprise web application - a locally hosted website that provides the desired functionality.

I want to build this web application, but build it such that -

- Its more of a product than a one-time solution; such that it can be customized for different clients
- It is possible to provide 'fixes' for this web application, so that bugs can be removed and enhancements added with minimum impact on operations
- The web app should be capable of working with different databases and existing authentication systems

Is this even possible? Is it a common enough approach that there is a known way of going about this? Would it be better to use an application framework like Spring or try and keep dependencies on frameworks to minimal?

Also, any links or references to books that will guide me will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance StackOverflow!

(I feel like I dont know all what I need to know before embarking on this project, please feel free to point out things I haven't and should consider)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "customized for different clients". A webapp should be usable with any browser client.

Comment: Java = an extremely generic tool that can serve many purposes. A Twitter client = an extremely specialized tool that can't do much else. What you want = somewhere in between. Sure it's possible, but being too generic is useless for the customer and being too specialized is not useful for other customers.

Answer (score 2):

Developing software, esp. for re-usability, requires analyzing which parts/functions are common between use cases and which aren't, drawing the line between re-usable (library) and customized/specialized code.

If you know what use cases you expect or want to support in the future this can be feasible.
If you don't, you should not start trying to generalize arbitrary functionality in the first place, because you cannot know what you will be needing in the future.

Java provides some good abstractions of various functionalities, like universal DB support via JDBC.

If you didn't already, have a look at application servers like JBoss or Glassfish. They provide plenty of basic functionality for web applications, support very loose coupling between components, and are highly configurable. To switch from one DBMS to another, for instance, it is enough to alter a single line of configuration (given the supported SQL is similar enough). Deploying applications or parts can often be done on the fly ("hot deployment") without even stopping the server.
Plus: There is a vast amout of supporting libraries and frameworks out there to help you standardize your application design.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working for a while on a webapp that can be deployed in multiple locations: it is designed to be instantiated on many hosts. It's entirely possible to do this, *but it is difficult*. Writing the code so that it can work this way takes a great deal of care.

The key to doing it is to make all your dependencies on things explicit and all your configuration driven by properties that can be set during installation. Spring makes this quite a lot easier! In particular, the `org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class allows you to use the servlet context as a source of values that you can then inject into your beans (e.g., via `@Value` annotations). It's far harder to do all that yourself. Here's (a simplified version of) what I use:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="contextOverride" value="true" />
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/default.properties" />
</bean>
```

This merges the servlet context's properties on top of the ones you provide as defaults inside your webapp (definitely a good practice if most things aren't going to need to be modified most of the time) and then uses them to define properties. I then apply a configuration property (e.g., `foo.bar`) to a bean property using a placeholder, like this:

```
@Value("${foo.bar}")
public void setFoobar(String foobar) { ... }
```

Things to configure that way include the database configuration, absolute locations of files holding things that can't be packaged inside the webapp, etc. You'll have to use your skill and knowledge of the application domain to work out what things need to be listed.

Other key principles are to keep as much as possible inside the webapp (so reducing the opportunity for the deployer to mess it up), to be very careful about documenting everything, and to try it with multiple servlet containers. Remember, the person deploying your webapp *does not* have access to the contents of your thoughts: you have to write it down and tell them exactly what to do. (Too many instructions are at the level of “click this, click that, magic happens” but those are poor instructions since the exact method will vary over time: saying *why* will help far more because its more portable.)

Answer (score 1):

We are currently developing a product that can be deployed internally for multiple clients and also as a public portal solution. Here is our experience.

As others have pointed out, there are different factors to keep in mind.

- Security
- Security that is associated with your product, and how you would manage the product functional requirements to external security roles.
- Security, authentication and authorization should not be as part of the base product. Once authorized the roles need to be mapped to product roles for achieving said functionality.
- Images and logos, that require customization.
- Internationalization.
- For working with multiple databases, assuming a product has typically two different views, persistence and querying. Our experience was to use hibernate to support multiple databases, but theoretically we have used only two databases in the past. db2 and mysql.
- Testing for multiple databases for every release of your product is a pain. Your test cases goes 3 fold or atleast once in a while to support multiple databases.
- Using custom databases and functions are a big no, you can use some general functions but custom database specific functions in your query are going to be a pain and have to be very diligent to avoid them.
- Supported browsers in your product.
- Licenses of the third party jars may not be compatible / acceptable to all institutions so you have to watch out for that carefully.
- As much as possible, enable properties or configuration to customize all variables.
- Caching strategy and properties initialization strategies.

A framework helps the team to keep on the same page, rather than an internal framework. There are many advantages to use a well established framework like Spring for performance and other consideration.

Cheers!